# number of points within a radius of another set of points

Tags: postgresql, postgis, cartodb

I have two tables. One is a list of stores (with lat/long). The other is a list of customer addresses (with lat/long). What I want is a query that will return the number of customers within a certain radius for each store in my table. This gives me the total number of customers within 10,000 meters of ANY store, but I'm not sure how to loop it to return one row for each store with a count.

Note that I'm doing this queries using cartoDB, where `the_geom` is basically long/lat.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as customer_count FROM customer_table 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM store_table
    WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(store_table.the_geom, customer_table.the_geom) < 10000
)
```

This results in a single row :

```
customer_count
4009
```

Suggestions on how to make this work against my problem? I'm open to doing this other ways that might be more efficient (faster).

For reference, the column with store names, which would be in one column is `store_identifier.store_table`

Comment: don't use `count(*)`. `select * ...` instead, then use num_rows() to quickly determine how many stores matched.

Comment: I have answered your later - very similar - question. I would suggest that you delete this question altogether as it appears to be superseded by your later question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of points within certain ranges from a set of points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179085/count-number-of-points-within-certain-ranges-from-a-set-of-points)

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you use `the_geom` to represent the coordinate (lat/lon) of store and customer. I will also assume that `the_geom` is of `geography` type. Your query will be something like this

```
select s.id, count(*) as customer_count
from customers c
inner join stores s 
  on st_dwithin(c.the_geom, s.the_geom, 10000)
group by s.id
```

This should give you neat table with a store id and count of customers within 10,000 meters from the store.

If `the_geom` is of type `geometry`, you query will be very similar but you should use `st_distance_sphere()` instead in order to express distance in kilometers (not degrees).

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct, but this gave me the same number for every store location...the total number of rows in my customer table.

Comment: `ST_Distance_Sphere()` in the question works perfectly fine with a lon\lat `geometry`, returning a distance in meters.

Comment: @jonmrich Apparently your `the_geom` field is not of the `geography` data type (`ST_DWithin()` using lon/lat and reporting in meters), but of `geometry` data type in lon/lat units (SRID of 4326, WGS84) with `ST_DWithin()` using lon/lat as both input and output. In other words, the value "10000" is understood to mean "10,000 degrees of separation on the sphere". Hence all store locations have all customers "nearby".