# Count number of points within certain distance ranges from another set of points

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following, which gives me the number of customers within 10,000 meters of any store location:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as customer_count FROM customer_table c
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM locations_table s
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(s.the_geom, c.the_geom) < 10000
)
```

What I need is for this query to return not only the number of customers within 10,000 meters, but also the following. The number of customers within...

1. 10,000 meters
2. more than 10,000, but less than 50,000
3. more than 50,000, but less than 10,0000
4. more than 100,000

...of any location.

I'm open to this working a couple of ways. For a given customer, only count them one time (the shortest distance to any store), which would count everyone exactly once. I realize this is probably pretty complex. I'm also open to having people be counted multiple times, which is really the accurate values anyway and think should be much simpler.

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both types of queries relatively easily. But an issue here is that you do not know which customers are associated with which store locations, which seems like an interesting thing to know. If you want that, use the PK and `store_name` of the `locations_table` in the query. See both options with location id and store_name below. To emphasize the difference between the two options:

- The first option indicates how many customers are in every distance class for every store location, for **all customers for every store location**.
- The second option indicates how many customers are in every distance class for every store location, for **the nearest store location for each customer** only.

This is a query of `O(n x m)` running order (implemented with the `CROSS JOIN` between `customer_table` and `locations_table`) and likely to become rather slow with increasing numbers of rows in either table.

### Count customers in all distance classes

You should make a `CROSS JOIN` between the distances of customers from store locations and then group them by the store location id, name and classes of maximum distance that you define. You can create a "table" from your distance classes with the `VALUES` command which you can then simply use in any query:

```
SELECT loc_dist.id, loc_dist.store_name, grps.grp, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT s.id, s.store_name, ST_Distance_Sphere(s.the_geom, c.the_geom) AS dist
    FROM customer_table c, locations_table s) AS loc_dist
JOIN (
    VALUES(1, 10000.), (2, 50000.), (3, 100000.), (4, 1000000.)
  ) AS grps(grp, dist) ON loc_dist.dist < grps.dist
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

### Count customers in the nearest distance class

If you want customers listed in the nearest distance class only, then you should make the same `CROSS JOIN` on `customer_table` and `locations_table` as in the previous case, but then simply select the lowest group (i.e. the closest store) using a `CASE` clause in the query and `GROUP BY` store location id, name and distance class as before:

```
SELECT 
  id, store_name,
  CASE
    WHEN dist <  10000. THEN 1
    WHEN dist <  50000. THEN 2
    WHEN dist < 100000. THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END AS grp,
  count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT s.id, s.store_name, ST_Distance_Sphere(s.the_geom, c.the_geom) AS dist
    FROM customer_table c, locations_table s) AS loc_dist
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks for the detailed answer. The first bit of code you gave me works great and is more than I was expecting. One question with that. How can I add in another column from the `locations_table` into the final result? This would be a column `store_name`. Is that possible?

The second bit of code didn't work for me. It's giving me an error: "missing FROM-clause entry for table "cust_dist""

Comment: One more question...for the first bit of code, rather than outputting all distance `grp` for each location, I tried to just get a single row for each distance group by removing `loc_dist.id` from the `SELECT`. This worked, but gave me numbers that don't make sense. For `grp` 4, the value is greater than the number of people in my customer database. I'd expect the max value would be the number of people.

Comment: Re. the error: I use `cust_dist` in the `CASE` clause, but that should be `loc_dist`; see updated answer. (Initially I worked with cust_dist, but from your other question I realized you were interested in where customers live relative to store locations, so I changed the table names.)

Comment: Taking out `loc_dist.id` from the first query makes very little sense, at the very least for distance class 4. It will give you an overall sum of how many customers are in each distance class, for all stores combined. Remember that all customers are in distance class 4 of all shops, so you should get a total count of 4x the number of customers.

Comment: Re. the `store_name`: You can simply add this in the sub-query and then `GROUP BY` in the main query; see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional assistance and detail. With your updated code (second one), now I'm getting an error at `CASE`. Figured it out though...I think missing a comma after `store_name` in that second line.